# In R, how can I check for the existence of a function in an unloaded package?

Tags: r, package, exists

I can check that a function exists in my environment:

```
> exists("is.zoo")
[1] FALSE
```

I can check that a function exists after loading a package by loading it:

```
> library(zoo)
> exists("is.zoo")
[1] TRUE
```

But how can I check that a function exists in a package *without* loading that package?

```
> exists("zoo::is.zoo")
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I believe you need to look into the package source. Exported functions you often can find easily in the NAMESPACE file, but usually you should find them also in the package's documentation. Otherwise you need to check the actual source files.

Comment: I need to be able to check programmatically.

Comment: Why do you need to check this programmatically?

Comment: You could cheat by writing a function which loads the library, checks for the function, then unloads the library and returns the existence value.

Comment: Not at a machine w/ R installed right now, so can't test, but maybe playing with the `:::` operator to search NAMESPACE might cover most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exists` function to look inside namespaces:

```
exists2 <- function(x) {

    assertthat::assert_that(assertthat::is.string(x))

    split <- base::strsplit(x, "::")[[1]]

    if (length(split) == 1) {
        base::exists(split[1])
    } else if (length(split) == 2) {
        base::exists(split[2], envir = base::asNamespace(split[1]))
    } else {
        stop(paste0("exists2 cannot handle ", x))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can view the source of a function even if its not loaded.

```
> exists("zoo::is.zoo")
[1] FALSE
> zoo::is.zoo
function (object)
inherits(object, "zoo")
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

So you could exploit that with a function like this

```
exists_unloaded <- function(fn) {
  tryCatch( {
    fn
    TRUE
  }, error=function(e) FALSE
  )
}
```

If the call to `fn` errors, it'll return FALSE; if `fn` shows the source, the `TRUE` will be returned.

```
> exists("zoo::is.zoo")
[1] FALSE
> exists_unloaded(zoo::is.zoo)
[1] TRUE
> exists_unloaded(zoo::is.zootoo)
[1] FALSE
```

(Just be careful, as written `exists_unloaded` returns `TRUE` for all strings. Probably want to error if `fn` is a string.)

edit:

Also, you can call a function without loading the package. I don't know your full use case, but it might obviate the need to check for its existence. (Of course, if the user hasn't installed the package, it will still fail.)

```
> exists("zoo::is.zoo")
[1] FALSE
> zoo::is.zoo(1)
> z <- zoo::as.zoo(1)
> zoo::is.zoo(z)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `parseNamespaceFile('zoo', .libPaths(),mustExist = TRUE)`  may be useful here

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you call `zoo::is.zoo()`, that loads the package, as you can see with `isLoadedNamespace("zoo")`. It doesn't attach the package to the search path. But you can have problems with unloading it later - see `detach`.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to clutter the search path using `loadNamespace` would work in conjunction with `getAnywhere`

Note that this will find functions unexported or exported...

```
loadNamespace('zoo')
x <- getAnywhere('is.zoo')
x[['where']]=='namespace:zoo'
# TRUE
```

Wrap it in a function

```
exist_pkg <- function(f, pkg){
  loadNamespace(pkg)
  x <- getAnywhere(f)
  paste0('namespace:',pkg) %in% x[['where']]
}
```

you could be careful unloading namespaces afterwards if you really wanted

You could also use `getFromNamespace`

```
is.function(getFromNamespace("is.zoo", "zoo"))
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a pretty answer, and it probably has some flaws to it, but it's a start.

```
is_exported <- function(fn, pkg){
  nmsp <- readLines(system.file("NAMESPACE", package = pkg))
  nmsp <- paste0(nmsp, collapse = " ")

  Exports <- stringr::str_extract_all(nmsp,
                                   stringr::regex("(?<=export[(]).+?(?=[)])"))
  Methods <- stringr::str_extract_all(nmsp,
                                   stringr::regex("(?<=S3method[(]).+?(?=[)])"))

  any(grepl(stringr::regex(fn), c(Exports, Methods)))
}

is_exported("is.zoo", "zoo")
```

Comment: This is roughly what `devtools::parse_ns_file` does. The problem is that some NAMESPACE files use `exportPattern` and therefore don't mention exported objects by name... which means this approach has intermittent bugs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this needs a more accurate answer.

Short version: you can't.

To see why, consider the following code in a package:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("foo <- func", "tion () 1 + 1")))
```

This will create a function `foo`. But you will only learn that by running the R code.

You could check the NAMESPACE file for `export(foo)`, but unfortunately the author might have written something like `exportPattern("f.*")`, so that won't be reliable either.

Long version: you can't avoid loading the package, but you can avoid attaching it. In other words, R will interpret the package source files (and load any dlls), and will store the package in memory, but it won't be directly available on the search path.

```
ns <- loadNamespace(package)
exists("foo", ns)
```

You can then unload the namespace with `unloadNamespace(package)`. But see the warnings in `?detach`: this is not always guaranteed to work! `loadNamespace(package, partial = TRUE)` *may* be helpful, or maybe `devtools::load_all` and `devtools::unload` do something cleverer, I don't know.

Some answers are suggesting stuff like `try{package::foo}`. The problem is that this itself loads the namespace:

```
> isNamespaceLoaded("broom")
[1] FALSE
> try(broom::tidy)
function(x, ...) UseMethod("tidy")
<environment: namespace:broom>
> isNamespaceLoaded("broom")
[1] TRUE
```